# Test and Train AUC are almost exactly the same

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic

I am trying to build a logistic regression model. My test and training sets are generating almost the same AUC. Ideally- this means that the model is performing very well. But since, I got this result at my very first attempt of building this model- I am a bit skeptical in accepting the fact that I have come up with a great model. I want to make sure that nothing else is going on with my process.

Test AUC
0.7606003279815455
Train AUC
0.7613571317318779

Note: The output class is imbalanced: 10%-90% split of 1 and 0 values. So I implemented undersampling by selecting all the observations from the minority class and 3*(number of observations from minority class) from majority class.

```
Here is my code (After data processing)

    df_item_date_level_v6 = df_item_date_level_v5.loc[:,~df_item_date_level_v5.columns.duplicated()].copy()

X=df_item_date_level_v6.drop(["sales_ind"], axis=1)
y=df_item_date_level_v6.loc[:,["sales_ind"]]


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42, train_size = .75)

lr = LogisticRegression(C=1.0,
                      class_weight=None,                     
                      dual=False,
                      fit_intercept=True,
                      intercept_scaling=1,
                      max_iter=1000, 
                      multi_class='ovr',
                      n_jobs=1,
                      penalty='l1', 
                      random_state=None, 
                      solver='liblinear',
                      tol=0.0001,
                      verbose=0 
                      )
#lr = LogisticRegression() 
                      

lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

train_score=lr.score(X_train, y_train)
test_score=lr.score(X_test, y_test)

print(lr.intercept_)
print(lr.coef_)

#Plotting AUC
#predict_proba generates the predicted value of Y in the very first column. 

train_fpr, train_tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_train,lr.predict_proba(X_train)[:,1]) 
test_fpr, test_tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, lr.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])

plt.plot(train_fpr, train_tpr, label="trainAUC="+str(metrics.auc(train_fpr,train_tpr)))
 
plt.plot(test_fpr, test_tpr, label="test AUC ="+str(metrics.auc(test_fpr, test_tpr))) 
plt.legend() 
plt.xlabel("FPR") 
plt.ylabel("TPR") 
plt.title("ROC for Train and Test data with best_fit")
plt.grid() 
plt.show()
```